# casmcard wrapper

Tags: c#, c++, smartcard

I've got a smartcard together a simple sdk written in C++ (casmcard.dll).

I need to call some method in above dll through managed code (C#) specially to read and write some particular block or sector.

No casmcard.dll wrapper found.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to dig into interop. If it's a COM object, you can import it & have .net create the wrapper for you. If it's old school dll functions, then you just need to import them.

Interop is a bit of a black art, so you'll need to google around on mapping & marshalling types.

**Edit**

So your function looks like?

```
CasCLGetSN( IN SCARDHANDLE hCard, OUT LPBYTE pbCSNBuffer, IN DWORD cbCSNBufferSize, OUT LPDWORD pcbCSNLength )
```

Try this:

```
CasCLGetSN(ScardHandle hCard, out IntPtr pbCSNBuffer, UInt32 cbCSNBufferSize, out UInt32 pcbCSNLength)
```

You'll then need to use the overloaded `Marshal.Copy()` to get the contents of the pbCSNBuffer. Also check what the definition of scardHandle is. If it's a struct, then declare it & add the `Sequential` attribute to it.

Comment: It's a native dll, so I cannot achieve wrapper automatically simply by referencing its, however I've created a simple wrapper with PInvoke Signature Toolkit. My difficult is perform reading/writing operation of some blocks. The native dll (and my wrapper too) expose some function such us casMifarereadBlock() and similar, but they always go on error. I think I pass some bad parameter so I would try something with other wrapper, to see more example.

Comment: It could be the parameter types are not quite right. .net has methods to help you marshal values from native managed types to unmanaged types. You'll just need to use Google & the MSDN docs to ensure you're mapping the types correctly.

Comment: Not much documentation found about CasMifareReadBlock and so on. I'm lost. I can only execute Transimt method (it will send an Adpu command) but I'm not able to decide which block querying.

Comment: Do you have any description of the methods you're calling? Look at the types it's expecting & match them to managed types or marshal them if you need something like an array, or a string.

Comment: Sure, look at here some methods: CasCLGetSN(
IN SCARDHANDLE hCard,
OUT LPBYTE pbCSNBuffer,
IN DWORD cbCSNBufferSize,
OUT LPDWORD pcbCSNLength );

Comment: My hCard handle is correct. I've already try with out InPtr pbCSNBuffer, ref byte[], but none of them works fine. CasCLGetSN return a value different from 0 so I know that something is wrong.

Comment: a non-zero result should indicate what the error is. Other than that, I'm afraid I can't help any more. ref byte[] won't work it's expecting a pointer.

Comment: I'll try a lot of solutions. However, passing out IntPtr as pbCSNBuffer is the same that array byte. Same return code. No documentation found. I'have not idea.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11586/discussion-between-bit-and-simon-halsey)